# FileStream ReadAsync fails on HID device while synchronous Read works

Tags: .net, windows, f#, hid

I'm trying to read data from an USB device (a Dualshock4 controller) in F# and I am encountering some issues when trying to use `ReadAsync`; this is a minimized example of the code:

```
module Example =
  let ds4ReadBufSize = 64

  let read device =
    let buffer = Array.zeroCreate ds4ReadBufSize
    async {
      use file = File.OpenHandle(device, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite, FileOptions.Asynchronous ||| FileOptions.SequentialScan)
      use fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileAccess.Read)
      let! d = fileStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) |> Async.AwaitTask
      printfn "%d" read
    }
```

When I run this code passing my device id in the form `\\?\HID#VID_...` (see below for full id) this code fails with the following error:

```
The parameter is incorrect. : '\\?\HID#VID_054C&PID_09CC&MI_03#7&1F856D05&0&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}'
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.IO.Strategies.BufferedFileStreamStrategy.<ReadFromNonSeekableAsync>d__38.MoveNext()
```

If I replace the `ReadAsync` line with this and use the synchronous `Read` instead it works and I get the expected data from the controller.

```
let d = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
```

I'm on latest Windows 10 with all updates and using .NET6. Anyone can help me with what I am missing?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the call to `File.OpenHandle`. You're passing in a device ID instead of a path to the file you want to open?

Comment: Yes, I am taking inspiration from a few open source repos but apparently this way you can read data from a HID device and it *does* work when I do it synchronously. The minimised example in the post doesn't show it but I am also able to parse the buffer and it contains indeed the expected data (e.g. I press a key on the pad and the corresponding flag is flipped).

Comment: I see. This is just a guess, but I wonder if the `use` statements are causing the resources to be disposed before you're done using them. I'd be curious to know what happens if you replace `use` with `let` or `use!`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I tried `use!` or `let!` but they won't compile (the values are not `Async`). I also tried moving the `use` outside of `async` and that made it fail with a different error explicitly stating that the file was closed (which makes sense), so I guess if that was the problem I should see the same error.

Comment: Try `let` without the exclamation point. That will prevent `Dispose` from being called until the garbage collector reclaims the objects.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I tried that too: it doesn't change the result. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: This is probably an issue related to Seekabel / Non Seekabel streams. You might want to check the sources - seems like a bug or limitation of the current implementation.

Comment: This seems to be fixed in net6.0.1 https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/61410